# "Rather ugly guys" or "guys rather ugly"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

> 1. **Rather ugly guys** came into the line.
> 2. **Guys rather ugly** came into the line.

The first one sounds fine to me but the second one sounds off to my ear.

Comment: The second one *can* be correct. It depends on the context. I'd be inclined to say that is rather literary; possibly even archaic.

Comment: The second one seems to be a shortened form of "Guys (that are) rather ugly came into the line. As mentioned by @DogLover this example might be OK in some literary context, but this is not a normal phrasing.

Comment: To make the second sentence have something similar, use *"A few guys, who were rather ugly, came into the line"*

Comment: @viktorahlström Or, if you really wanted to use the second sentence: *Guys - rather ugly - came into the line.*

Comment: Yeah—but with em dashes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Works.
2. Is acceptable but rather awkward.

I agree with your original assessment.